# When I type in connect() to my database, my localhost server comes up blank

Tags: php, mysql

Is the connect() function depecrated or something? When I try to connect to a mysql database using that function, my page stops working? 
i'm doing jeffrey ways 30daysjquery course lesson 25

here's the code in my index.php file

```
<?php 
require 'functions.php'

if ( isset($_POST['q'])) {
    connect();
}

include 'views/index.tmpl.php' 

?>
```

This is my code in my functions.php file

```
<?php 

function connect(){
    global $pdo; // set it as global so other functions can access it
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sakila", "root", "root");
}

function get_actors (){

}
?>
```

Might it be that I do not have access to the content that's in functions.php? if it is how do I create access?

Comment: so put the global keyword after $pdo?

Comment: No, if you want `$pdo` to be global, declare it in the global scope (outside your function).

Comment: Just did that I put 
    global $pdo; 
outside of my function and still blank page

Comment: Please check your PHP error log or Error reporting settings.

Comment: thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php on line 5
[09-Nov-2014 23:01:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php(9): connect()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/index.php(3): require('/Applications/M...')
#3 {main}

Comment: Just wanted to say that blank pages usually sound like fatal errors. Are you sure you have configured PDO in your php.ini?

Comment: could not find driver. It says everything. [look here about mysql and PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your function should maybe return a connection:

```
function connect(){
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sakila", "root", "root");
    return $pdo;
}
```

Then, your function `get_actors()` could be

```
$db_connection = connect();
get_actors( $db_connection );


function get_actors( $pdo ) {
    //
    // You use the database connection $pdo to get actors
    //
}
```

You have to add a parameter to your function `get_actors`. No need to modify the code into the function.

Comment: Tried everything you said and still get a blank page :(

Comment: @DCastillo You will have more details about the error in your web server log.

Comment: I get this  
    load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:8888/lesson-25/index.php

Comment: Generally, an error with a code 500 does not give you details on the page. As I wrote before, you have to check your log. It can be anything... Database not started, wrong database name, syntax error, wrong credentials...

Comment: which server-Software? check phpinfo(), is PDO aviable? what php-Version?

Comment: I'm using MAMP 
PHP Version 5.6.1

yes PDO is available

Answer (score 0):

When I checked MAMP this is the information I have if I want to connect to a MySQL server using a script.

```
Host    localhost
Port    8889
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php on line 5
[09-Nov-2014 23:01:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/functions.php(9): connect()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesson-25/index.php(3): require('/Applications/M...')
#3 {main}
```

Comment: Update your question instead of adding informations as an answer. As I said previously, check the log of your web server...